# How to prevent toolbar button focus in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtoolbar

In my Java Swing application I am using a `JToolBar` with several buttons. After the toolbar object is being created I call `setFocusable(false)`. However, every time I start the application the first button in the toolbar is focused.

Any ideas how I can prevent the toolbar buttons to come into focus at all?

Comment: Do you set the toolbar **buttons** to be nonfocusable?

Comment: Probably it is better to use button.setFocusPainted(false).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Toolbar buttons should not have

```
setFocusable(false)
```

called on them, as it breaks keyboard support. Rather, call:

```
setRequestFocusEnabled(false)
```

which will stop them from taking over the focus when the mouse clicks them, but still lets keyboard-centric users "tab over" to them.

You probably want to select some other sensible component to place the initial keyboard focus onto. So just call:

```
otherComponent.requestFocusInWindow();
```